# Error: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path in spring data rest

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, rest

this is the code:

```
@Import(Appconfig.class)
@RestController
//@RequestMapping("/api/destination/find")
public class RestApi01_Controller {

    @Autowired
    public CountryRepo Country_Repository;

    @Autowired
    public CityRepo City_Repository;

    @Autowired
    public AirportRepo Airport_Repository;

    @Autowired
    public ResortRepo  Resort_Repository;


   @RequestMapping(value="/api/destination/find/{city}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Master_City> getCity(@PathVariable String city) {

        return City_Repository.findByCityLikeIgnoreCase(city);
  }

    @RequestMapping(value="/api/destination/find/{airportname}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Master_Airport> getAirportname(@PathVariable String airportname) {

        return Airport_Repository.findByAirportnameLikeIgnoreCase(airportname);
  }

  @RequestMapping(value="/api/destination/find/{resortname}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Master_Resort> getResortname(@PathVariable String resortname) {

        return ResortRepository.findByResortnameLikeIgnoreCase(resortname);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ofcourse. You have 3 methods, mapping to same same URL. There is no way you can distinguish if something is an airport or city just by a path variable. `/api/destination/find/Amsterdam` you know it is a city but the for the code it is impossible to know.

Comment: Sir ,How to solve this issue??, I need to retrieve data from  3 mongodb collection using same path i.e /api/destination/find/{String}

Answer (score 0):

Your REST Endpoints are pointing basically to the same URI pattern.

Taking the first two as an example,

```
/api/destination/find/{city}
```

and

```
/api/destination/find/{airportname}
```

Since {city} and {airportname} are placeholders, and both the URI are HTTP GET methods, Spring is not able to make out which API to be used when a call to say `/api/destination/find/london`.

Instead of this, use request parameters. Something like this

```
/api/destination/find?airport={airportname}
```

and

```
/api/destination/find?city={city}
```

Comment: Sir ,How to solve this issue??, I need to retrieve data from 3 mongodb collection using same path i.e /api/destination/find/{String}

Comment: Can you pass a small request parameter in the URI, something like this - `/api/destination/find/{String}?type={type}`? Basically we need to differentiate each end point somehow, so type can be used for that to say city, airport or resort.

Comment: Sir my reqirements are : if a user enters "Lon", then
"Request: /api/destination/find/Lon
Response: [{""city"": {
{""city"": ""London"", ""indexid"":12355}, {""airport"":
{""airportcode"":""LCY"", ""airportname"": ""London City Airport""}, {""airportcode"":""LHR"", ""airportname"": ""London Heathrow""},{""resort"":
{""resortname"": ""London E Postcodes"", ""indexid"":26447}}

Comment: I think you do not need different end points for this requirement. You can achieve all this using a single endpoint, since the return type is same for whatever string is passed in the uri.

Comment: Sir one more help, how to limit the number of json fields from getting reponse from the url. All the field are showing .I need only 2 fields

Comment: @NareshGounder I would be so happy to answer that if you post a new question in SO, and pass me the link to it